# MySQL 8.1 does not let me login to my client after I disabled the SSL

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, ssl

I was facing some issues in my project due to the SSL being enabled so I followed the instructions given in other stack exchange questions to edit my my.ini file and add (# Disable SSL) skip_ssl but after adding this and restarting my SQL server. I am not able to access the server through my password, which made it worse for my project. I also tried to save my.ini file as ANSI encoding while removing a comment as it was told in another question on stack exchange MySql 8.0 starts and stops after my.ini is saved or edited in Windows 10 https://superuser.com/questions/1421016/mysql-8-0-starts-and-stops-after-my-ini-saved-or-edited-in-windows-10 but it still did not run. Now what should I do to fix this I am really facing a lot of issues due to this

Comment: Is this on your machine or in the cloud?

Comment: @RohitGupta Its on my machine.